# Is it possible to server php via NGINX without php-fpm (FastCGI)?

Tags: php, nginx

Is there any way to run and serve php via NGINX (without apache) AND without fast-cgi (php_fpm)

I'm asking this because in my CENTOS : i have apache + php 8 + nginx as reserved proxy...

*** and the moment I uninstalled php-fpm (fast cgi) my sites were 10X faster .....

I really don't like fast cgi especially for large file uploads like videos

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question right. The answer should be SURE

I think it have to have a reason why you running a apache2 (httpd) in front of the nginx?? ..these setup can work well (if you only use php stuff for the apache2 and proxy static to nginx, in this case nginx needs no special php setup)... I woulhd recommend uninstall the apache2 (httpd) and get php with nginx working (what isnt a difficult nowadays)  but please this is my first comment .. and not sure if I understand the question right..and if helps a bit .. im glad